# 'Error Could not contact Elasticsearch at http://localhost:9200.' - kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

'Error Could not contact Elasticsearch at http://localhost:9200. Please ensure that Elasticsearch is reachable from your system.'

Currently I am following http://packetbeat.com/getstarted

I installed

1. elastic search - running on localhost:9200 - returns the json,
   2.packetbeat - running,
2. Kibana on port 8000

Now, I change my kibana/config.js file - enter ,

```
elasticsearch: "http://"localhost":9200",
```

under elasticsearch. 
I get a plain white page with `{{dashboard.current.title}}` on top.

If I comment out `elasticsearch: "http://"localhost":9200",`

I get `Error Could not contact Elasticsearch at http://localhost:9200. Please ensure that Elasticsearch is reachable from your system.`

If I also enter it as `elasticsearch: "http://localhost:9200",`, I get the same error that it could not contact elasticsearch.

So, I am assuming `elasticsearch: "http://"localhost":9200",` is right, but it should render something. perhaps a UI

Comment: Sounds silly, but can you try http://localhost:9200 in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

put hostname instead of localhost
for example 
**http://bilal:9200**   (here bilal is my hostname)
if you dont know your hostname goto cmd or terminal type **hostname**

Answer (score 1):

this works for me..
instead of localhost set your public ip or public dns for
elasticsearch: "http://public_dns:80",

and set the port forwarding from 80 to 9200.

Answer (score 0):

Have `Kibana` auto-detect the `ElasticSearch` URL by using

```
elasticsearch: "http://"+window.location.hostname+":9200",
```

instead of `elasticsearch: "http://"localhost":9200"`

Answer (score 0):

Dont change anything, for default elasticsearch is in port 9200:

The Elasticsearch instance to use for all your queries.

elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"

The problem is that perhaps you must put elasticsearch.url and you only put elasticsearch: "http://localhost:9200".